# Using Reg expressions to search through HTML? [swift 1.2]

Tags: html, ios, regex, xcode, swift

Im trying to perform a screen scrape because i can't find a relevant free API to get the data i need. I've managed to perform the scrape and grab the HTML  page but the part i'm stuck on is getting the relevant information out of the grabbed content. I'm guessing i will need to use REG expressions to search through the HTML but unsure how to do this. the information I'm after is MAKE, MODEL, YEAR of the current car search.

```
 var url = NSURL(string: "https://www.rac.co.uk/buying-a-car/car-passport/report/buyer/purchase/?BuyerVrm=yg06dxt")

    if url != nil {
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            print(data)

            if error == nil {

                var urlContent = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding) as NSString!

                print(urlContent)
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }


}
```

heres a sample of the retuned information

```
<p class="CarMiniProfile-caveat u-hidden">*image for illustrative purposes only</p>

            <div>
                <table class="CarMiniProfile-table">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="CarMiniProfile-tableFirstRow">
                            <td class="CarMiniProfile-tableHeader">
                                Make
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                FIAT
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="CarMiniProfile-tableHeader">
                                Model
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                PUNTO SPORTING M-JET
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="CarMiniProfile-tableHeader">
                                Colour
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                BLUE
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="CarMiniProfile-tableHeader">
                                Year
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                2006
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="CarMiniProfile-tableHeader">
                                Engine Size
                            </td>
                            <td>
```

1910 cc

```
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

            <h3 class="CarMiniProfile-subheading">Check this car in 3 simple steps...</h3>
```

Comment: Don't use regex for HTML. Enjoy: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2227743

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regexes for html isn't a good idea, I agree.  Sometimes I've had to do some real nasty stuff with regexes and html.

If you absolutely must do it this way then here's one for MAKE:

```
<td.*?CarMiniProfile-tableHeader.*?\n*(.*?)\n*<\/td>
```

You should be able to customise this for everything else you need.  Using regexes is definitely not a recommended solution for this though.

Comment: thanks for that. if not using regexes whats a better way to do this would you suggest?

Comment: no problem.  Maybe something like this would help you:  http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.75/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm